# Show one row only in same id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to ask how to show one row only in same id, in below example, I just want to show the highest score result in the table.

**Here is my code**

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM memberdata ORDER BY score DESC";
    echo "<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th> id </th>
    <th> score </th>

    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['score'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
```

**And the Output is**

```
id score 
1  5000
1  4000
1  3000
1  500
2  3000
2  1000
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM memberdata ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: It will just show one output. But I would like to display all id

Comment: if you want to only show the highest score for each `id` (not only the best one), you need to `GROUP BY id` and `SELECT MAX(score) AS score` - as already answered by other users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Group by

```
SELECT id, MAX(score) AS score FROM memberdata GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I try to use this. but why the score will become empty?

Comment: You might have to give the column a name, I updated my query.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, MAX(score) AS score FROM memberdata GROUP BY id
```

or this:

```
SELECT * FROM memberdata ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate to find the maxrow first.

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM memberdata ORDER BY score DESC";
    echo "<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th> id </th>
    <th> score </th>

    </tr>";

    $maxrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($maxrow['score'] > row['score']) maxrow = row;
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $maxrow['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $maxrow['score'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Why would you go through so much calculations if you could save time and code by simply adapting your SQL query?

Comment: @lcefyre Well the other answers are better if the record with the highest score is all the OP wants. What I suggested would be useful only if he needs to do something with the other records as well